# Execute Fetchxml in MSCRM using java

Tags: java, web-services, dynamics-crm

I would like to know how to execute fetchxml on microsoft CRM web services using java? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can execute FetchXML in Dynamics CRM from JAVA, but you can have a look at the SDK in the following location for sample code of retrieving records from Dynamics CRM using JAVA :

`\SDK\Walkthroughs\Java2CRM\Java2CRMCRUD`

Also, you can check if you can access any function called `Execute` which is generally used to execute a FetchXML request.